# Internal pages not found (404) after moving to new host - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, web-hosting, transfer

I have recently moved one website to new server. I have transferred everything properly including mysql database. But now the internal pages are not opening (sending 404 error). Homepage looks fine.

One thing to consider here is that, the website was on shared cpanel with another domain and residing in a folder. Now after moving, it is placed directly in public_html. I hope, this doesn't create any issue.

The website is: http://nepaltrekking.co.kr/

regards,

Comment: Have you made sure you have only the first letter upper case on controllers classes and file names explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Comment: Yes. Naming is all okay.

Comment: You may need a new htaccess in your main directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I resolved it. The issue was with .htaccess. I changed the permission to 666 and it started working. I think there was problem writing in the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

When hosting changes, we need to take care of the following steps for codeigniter:

1. Check required php and apache modules are installed and enabled.
2. If installation is not in root directory, you must change htaccess.
3. If domain is changed, you need to edit config file for new base_url.
4. Clear application cache if enabled. Give required write permision in cache directory.
5. If nothing works, then see error log and correct error accordingly.